# The authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: c#, mono, certificate, raspbian

First a bit history...

A while ago I did some experiments wit C# and Home automation API from AVM (With a Fritz!Box router).
This means I am not very experienced with C# and/or the security mechanisms applied.

The API can be accessed by reading XML and JSON documents from the URL of the router.

For this purpose I tried to read a XML document from the Fritz!Box:

```
         try
         {
            doc = XDocument.Load(uri);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           ...
         }
```

The `uri` contains "https://" and the IP address or host name ("fritz.box") or the external myfritz address.

Unfortunately the certificates provided by the router are self signed certificates.
Firefox only likes them after adding an exception for that certificate.

Mono also does not like it.
I managed to solve this issue with these extra lines of code:

```
   static int Main(string[] args)
   {
       System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
       delegate (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                                System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
       {
           return true; // ****Always accept
       };
       ...
```

As the only URL that will ever be used by that program is the internal IP address or the external ***.myfritz.net URL of my Fritz!Box, I think I can live with accepting all certificates.

The program was developed on Windows 7 & 10 machine using Visual Studio 2015.
Afterwards it was compiled for Mono on the Raspberry:

```
dmcs /r:System.Xml.Linq /r:System.Web.Extensions Fritz_AHA_JSON.cs
```

And it was run every few minutes by a cronjob using this command line:

```
mono Fritz_AHA_JSON.exe
```

This solution worked fine for some years.

Now the router was exchanged. Instead of a Fritz!Box 7390 there is a Fritz!Box 7590 model installed.

If I access the new router from Windows 10 using Firefox, everything is fine after adding the exception for the certificate.

If I access the router using the same C# code from within Visual Studio 15 on Windows 10, everything works fine again.

If I run the C# program with Mono on the Raspberry Pi, the certificate is rejected.

```
Fehlerbeschreibung: System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ProcessAlert (AlertLevel alertLevel, AlertDescription alertDesc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity (System.Uri absoluteUri, System.String role, System.Type ofObjectToReturn) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.GetStreamFromUrl (System.String url, System.String& absoluteUriString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader..ctor (Boolean dummy, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.String url, XmlNodeType fragType, System.Xml.XmlParserContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor (Boolean dummy, System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver, System.String url, XmlNodeType fragType, System.Xml.XmlParserContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create (System.String inputUri, System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings, System.Xml.XmlParserContext inputContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create (System.String inputUri, System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.String uri, LoadOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.String uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at AVM_AHA.Program.GetSessionId (System.String URL, System.String benutzername, System.String kennwort) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Searching for a solution I found hints to install the same verification callback as I have.
Another solution I found was

```
mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

which doesn't really work well:

> Mozilla Roots Importer - version 3.2.8.0 Download and import trusted
>   root certificates from Mozilla's MXR. Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus
>   Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.
>
> Downloading from
>   'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...
>   Couldn't retrieve the file using the supplied information.

The Mono version installed on Raspi is

> Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)

The problem started with changing the router. There were no updates done on the Raspberry Pi.

The strange thing is that it seems that my verification callback is not even called.
I've added some `Console.Writeln()` before returning `true` but do not see anything on the console. 
In Windows I can see the extra lines.

For me this would mean that the problem happens already before the certificate is to be verified.
As I am not that familiar with certificate handling in Mono, i have no idea where to look for a sulution.

Comment: No idea, but it's a TlsException, which suggests there are problems connecting via a secure socket. If this is a new box, it might be tls 1.2 only. Not sure what versions of TLS are supported by default in mono, but I've experienced a similar situation where my website was going with the defaults (tls 1.0) and customers rightfully were disabling that and going to 1.2. We had to tell the framework to not be insecure and stuff. You know, go to the gym and get a cool jacket or something.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't really sound promising. The Mono version on the Raspi seems to be a bit old. I am not sure if I can get a more recent version that includes TLS 1.2 support.

Comment: As a temporary workaround I changed from https to http which is still available for connectionf from the LAN. This works fine but it does not work for external access via external myfritz address.